# UITableView reorder control not hiding

Tags: ios, uitableview

*I'm using Xcode 10.0 beta 4, so this might just be a bug.*

---

#### The goal:

Hide the reordering control that appears when allowing reordering of a `UITableViewCell`, or overlay it on the table view cell instead of it moving the table view cell to the side.

#### The problem:

Setting `showsReorderControl = false` for the table view cells is not having any effect.

---

#### The situation:

**CategoryTableViewCell:**

```
class CategoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

   // `colorPanel` is constrained via auto layout to the cell's borders minus an inset.
   @IBOutlet weak var colorPanel: ColorPanel!

   //...
}
```

**ColorPanel**

```
// Pure 'UIView's are not drawn during table view cell reordering. This is a workaround for that.
class ColorPanel: UIView {

   // Makes sure the view is never cleared.
   override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
      didSet {
         if backgroundColor?.cgColor.alpha == 0 {
            backgroundColor = oldValue
         }
      }
   }

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      layer.cornerRadius = 20
      translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   }
}
```

**CategoryTableViewController:**

```
class CategoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      tableView.rowHeight = 70

      tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
   }

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      tableView.reloadData()
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
         withIdentifier: "CategoryTableViewCell",
         for: indexPath
      ) as! CategoryTableViewCell

      cell.showsReorderControl = false
      //...

      return cell
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
      return true
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
      return .none
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
      return false
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
      return true
   }

   //...
}
```

---

#### The output:

[image: Output]

---

What could I do to get rid of the reordering controls?

Comment: Reordering controls are shown in editing mode. Why is the table view set to editing mode by default?

Comment: @vadian I want to be able to rearrange the cells at all times.

Comment: OK. But If you *want to be able to rearrange the cells at all times* why do you want to hide the controls?

Comment: @vadian because they are pushing the table view cells' contents to the left. I want the content to be full width.

Comment: FYI: a detail that might concern some - When you use the older/classic UITableView "reorder control", the user must grab the "grippy" image, the row itself is not enabled for selection|long-press|force-touch -> dragging. 

The default behavior of the layer, might have (long ago) been meant to reflect that detail of the UI.

The broader "Drag and Drop" technology (added later by Apple) does appear let you pickup the row from anywhere view.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I was able to achieve reorder with hidden reorder control icon is to override **layoutSubviews** and set contentView's frame to match parent's bounds like following:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
}
```

Comment: This one works partially: 1) you need to make sure that your `contentView.backgroundColor` is not `.clear`. 2) The `zPosition` should be higher than the default one - `self.contentView.layer.zPosition = 10`. This will mess up with the red `delete` icon on the left side, but that one is another story )) It can be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue

adding this function solved it

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.showsReorderControl = false
}
```

make sure to call `tableView.reloadData()` the moment AFTER it goes into editing mode for I did it in an IBAction of a button like below

```
@IBAction func editButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
    tableView.reloadData()
    editRoutineButton.title = tableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
}
```

Comment: If you are able to programmatically turn the reorder control off, does that mean that there is no way to reorder the cells (since that accessory view was the element that you could "pick up"?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to have it both ways. From the documentation of `tableView(_:canMoveRowAt:)`

> This method allows the data source to specify that the reordering control for the specified row not be shown. By default, the reordering control is shown if the data source implements the tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:) method.

Based on the response from the delegate, the system will manage the state of the reorder control, as described in the documentation for `showsReorderControl`

> For the reordering control to appear, you must not only set this property but implement the UITableViewDataSource method tableView(*:moveRowAt:to:). In addition, if the data source implements tableView(*:canMoveRowAt:) to return false, the reordering control does not appear in that designated row.

By returning `true` from your delegate, the control will be shown.

Comment: If I return `false` from `tableView(:canMoveRowAt:)` I can not reorder the cells.

Comment: By implementing the delegate method, you're opting in to using the functionality provided by UITableView, which includes showing the reorder control under the circumstances described above. If you don't like the way it's done, you can remove the delegate method and implement your own scheme for reordering, but you have to do all the heavy lifting to implement the interaction and data model updates.